# Is it possible to move worker thread between AppDomains

Tags: c#, .net

I have to create procedure that will do fast close of multiple threads. My idea is to move all threads that has to be cancelled into new AppDomain, then abort all such threads and then unload that AppDomain.

Is that possible?

Comment: If you know which threads you want to abort, why not just abort them without trying to do that AppDomain dance?

Comment: Agree with @Anna - if you know what threads need to be aborted, why not just abort them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot move threads between app domains. Objects aren't actually moved between them.

See [Moving objects across AppDomains in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981773/moving-objects-across-appdomains-in-net).

I believe you will just need to handle the thread objects yourself and cancel them as needed.

Comment: I have found a link http://en.csharp-online.net/Building_Multithreaded_Applications and on next page it written "Although active threads can be moved between AppDomain boundaries, a given thread can execute within only a single application domain at any point in time (in other words, it is impossible for a single thread to be doing work in more than one AppDomain)"; as well "CLR is the entity that is in charge of moving threads into (and out of) application domains and contexts."

Comment: I guess some clarity should be included: `Thread` objects cannot be moved. The runtime can do whatever it wants with the underlying thread that `Thread` object represents.

Answer (score 1):

Aborting threads is a bad idea. Consider implementing cooperative cancellation. See how it's done in .Net 4 [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/22/9635790.aspx).
Here is a quote from that article:

> Any asynchronous technique has the common trait that the target of cancellation is caught completely unaware and cannot easily ensure data safety. For many reasons, but particularly due to the risk of partial updates to shared data, the use of asynchronous techniques is strongly discouraged.